# reference for higher spin - not gravitational nor stringy

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, physics, string-theory

Other than the papers of Berends, Burgers and van Dam, are there any papers that study the general case of deforming a free field theory with higher spin fields to be interactive?

Comment: On [PhysicsOverflow](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/27048/reference-for-higher-spin-not-gravitational-nor-stringy?show=27499#a27499), there is a link to [this paper](http://inspirehep.net/record/265411) for the same question.

Answer (score 1):

[Aspects of Higher-Spin Theory with Fermions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5319), Gustavo Lucena Gómez (2014).